# Finding the PDF of a continuous random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I was solving the following question:

> Find the PDF of the continuous random variable $X$ with CDF
> $$
> F(x) = \begin{cases}
> 0,        & x \le 0 \\
> 2x^2-x^3, & 0 \le x \le 1\\
> 1,        & x \ge 1
> \end{cases}
> $$

---

> I wrote $f(x) =F'(x) = 4x-6x^2$, so
> $$
> f(x) = \begin{cases}
> 4x-6x^2, & 0 \le x \le 1\\
> 0,       & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$

I can't find what's wrong with my answer. Is this the right answer or is it $4x-3x^2$?

Comment: The derivative of $x^3$ is $3x^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you correctly note, the PDF $f(x)$ is just the derivative of the given CDF $F(x)$. So, when $x \not \in (0,1)$, you can see that $F'(x) = 0$, and at $0,1$, the derivative is not defined.

But in $(0,1)$, you have
$$
f(x)
 = F'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \left[2x^2-x^3\right]
 = 2 \frac{d}{dx} \left[x^2\right] - \frac{d}{dx} \left[x^3\right]
 = 2(2x) - 3x^2 = 4x-3x^2.
$$

Comment: Man your edit was amazing! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @TheTower you are welcome. I hope you stay around and contribute to the site. When you post questions, it is much better to use MathJaX, formatted result looks much better. You can click on *Edit* on your question to see the source, or use this [MathJaX tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)